# Push Notification in android c2dm

Tags: php, android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I'am developing a sample push notification app in android using c2dm. Here is my PHP code to send the message from server to device.

```
function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) {

    $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
    $data = array(
        'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
        'collapse_key' => $msgType,
        'data.message' => $messageText //TODO Add more params with just simple data instead           
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
    if ($headers)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch); 

}
sendMessageToPhone("my application server auth token ","my device id","UTF-8","hello");
```

But i'am getting "No info." notification on my emulator. Where i'am going wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: What is the response from executing the cURL request? Are you sure that the emulator is registered to receive C2DM messages (i.e. is associated with a Google account)?  Did you include the C2DM permissions in its manifest? What version of Android?

Comment: I'am new to php. I'am getting some resource id if i return $response . And immediately i'am getting the notification on emulator. I have included all the permissions in manifest. Using 2.2

Comment: I'am getting the correct notification when i send a message from java application server. (Using java application server auth token)

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I've never seen the 'no info' problem. However my working PHP code is much the same, except I also have:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`

Additionally you can replace your curl_close line with this to flag any errors:

`if (curl_errno($ch))
{
 echo curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $response;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$token",     "Content-Length: $len", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    echo curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);`

This is the php code that my app uses to send C2DM messages where $data is your data array. Please note that the Content-Length is necessary and is is the length of your data.

EDIT: Something you may also find useful a [class](https://bitbucket.org/Dianoga/php-c2dm/src/0c299de8f10b/class.c2dm.php) for php that makes sending messages a little nicer.